# Flash 3.5.3 - breaking change on playing pre-recorded files?

Tags: flash, flash-media-server, fms3

installing Adobe FMS 3.5.3 seems to completely wipe out all our interactive applications, and I wondered if anybody else had the same experience.

Back in the happy days of 3.5.2, to add a pre-recorded file to a stream, we created the stream:

```
this.clientPlayStream = Stream.get (slrStreamName);
```

then added a file to it:

```
this.clientPlayStream.play ("MP3:fileName", 0, - 1, 0);
```

the deal was that the file to play ("fileName.mp3" in this example) was in the applications "streams\ *instancename* " subdirectory.  At the moment, I'm not sure where I learnt to do this, but whatever, it used to work a charm.

However, this isn't working in 3.5.3 - we're getting "file not found" errors. As we've got a couple of big apps about to go live that depend on this, we'd really appreciate it if anybody here knows more about this, and tell us what we're doing wrong.

Seeing as it hasn't come up already, I'm guessing that we were just exploiting a bug that's now been fixed (can't see anything in the release notes).

Much obliged

Toby

Answer (score 0):

panic over - we had a dodgy config file. For some reason, we had this as the first entry:

```
<StreamManager>
    <VirtualDirectory>
      <!-- Specifies application specific virtual directory mapping for streams.   -->
        <Streams>/;${LIVE_DIR}</Streams>
    </VirtualDirectory>

</StreamManager>
```

prior to 3.5.3, this made no difference, but it looks like Adobe have fixed the bug now, and actually redirect to the specified virtual directory for streams, as you might expect ...